# AngularJS dynamic ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have 
select

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="{{selectOptions}}">
        <option style="display:none" value="">Select country</option>
</select>
```

and json country list {id :..., nameEn: ..., nameRu: ...}

Can someone explain why this works:

```
$scope.lang = "En";
$scope.selectOptions = "country as country['name'+lang] for country in countries";
$scope.customerChanged = function(v){
    if (/[а-яА-ЯЁё]/.test(v))
        $scope.lang = "Ru";
    else
        $scope.lang = "En";
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
$scope.selectOptions = "country as country['nameEn'] for country in countries";
$scope.customerChanged = function(v){
    if (/[а-яА-ЯЁё]/.test(v))
        $scope.selectOptions = "country as country['nameRu'] for country in countries";
    else
        $scope.selectOptions = "country as country['nameEn'] for country in countries";
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="country as country.name{{lang}} for country in countries">
        <option style="display:none" value="">Select country</option>
</select>




$scope.lang = "En";
$scope.customerChanged = function(v){
    if (/[а-яА-ЯЁё]/.test(v))
        $scope.lang = "Ru";
    else
        $scope.lang = "En";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!--First Solution-->
<select ng-model="selectValue" ng-options="item.Name for item in items">
    <option selected value="">Select Value</option>
</select>

<!--Second Solution-->
<select ng-model="selectValue">
    <option  value="{{item.Value}}"  ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.Name}}
    </option>
</select>

<!--Third Solution-->
<select ng-model="selectValue" ng-options="item.Name for item in items">
</select>

<!--For Multiple Select--> 
<select ng-model="" multiple ng-options="">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

From  angular documentation:

> **Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:**
>
> There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because
>   interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses
>   attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw
>   interpolation markup and not data.